# Calculating a point's position on a line so the angle of two segments are equal.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'll try to explain the problem a bit better with the image attached.
So, given a line, as seen in the picture, and two points, C and D, 
I want to find the position of a third point, E, in a way that the angles formed by the line with CE and DE are equal. How do I do that?

I hope the explanation of the problem was clear enough. If not, let me know, I'll try my best. Thanks in advance. :)

[image: Problem]

[image: Third Point]

Comment: Can you show us which angles do you mean?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Of course, I meant these angles https://imgur.com/a/3FwUiEk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Hint: Find the point D', the mirror image of D.

Comment: Yes! As always I've overcomplicated the problem... Thank you very much! ^^